# Principal Component Analysis (PCA) issue on Spectral indices and transformations of Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, google-earth, google-maps-api, google-earth-api

Following the Principal Component Analysis (PCA) section on `Lab 4: Spectral indices and transformations` from https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/edu I reached a point which its not clear, in fact its black, as seen in the picture

[image]

And I'm not sure on how to ask it. May I just ask for help on executing this Principal Component Analysis (PCA) section on `Lab 4: Spectral indices and transformations`?

What's the meaning of the black body? Or is there a bug around here?

May I provide further info on the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the question!  In the future, please only use directly relevant tags.  This one should be tagged with "google-earth-engine", and not the others, to avoid spamming people watching those tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the stretching to visualize images manually. You can access this if you hover the mouse on the 'Layers' in the right top corner of the map. This is also noted in the tutorial you are following. See the pic:

[image]

You could also set these parameters in the code editor:

```
Map.addLayer(pcImage.select('pc1'), {min:-448, max:-398,}, 'PC');
```