# Google Earth Engine: PCA (Principal Component Analysis) issue with 'arrayFlatten' when applied on Sentinel-2 glcm texture bands

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, texture, eigen-values

I am trying to get PCA for glcm bands derived from sentinl-2 using following code

```
var S2S1comp = ee.Image("users/monishD/S2S1comp");
///2. ///Set "seeddist" and "glcmws" to define SNIC objects' size and radius size for GLCM analysis
var seeddist = 10;
var glcmws = 2;

//4. /////Classification
//4.1///Define classifier
// var classifier_alg="RF";

//4.5////Object_based
var seeds = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.seedGrid(seeddist);

var snic = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC({
  image: S2S1comp,
  compactness: 0,  
  connectivity: 8, 
  neighborhoodSize: 256, 
  seeds: seeds
});

print('snic',snic);

//Create and rescale a grayscale S2 image for textural indices calculation 
var S2gray = S2S1comp.expression(
      '(0.3 * NIR) + (0.59 * R) + (0.11 * G)', {
      'NIR': S2S1comp.select('B8'),
      'R': S2S1comp.select('B4'),
      'G': S2S1comp.select('B3')
}).rename('S2gray');//.updateMask(maskb);
print(S2gray,'S2gray');
Map.addLayer(S2gray,{min: 0.014, max: 0.26},'S2 grayscale',false);

var S2glcm = S2gray.unitScale(0.014, 0.26).multiply(255).toInt().glcmTexture({size: glcmws});
print(S2glcm,'S2 GLCM');

var S2glcm_sel = S2glcm.select([0,1,2,3,4,5,8],['S2asm','S2con','S2cor','S2var','S2idm','S2savg','S2ent']);
print(S2glcm_sel,'S2 GLCM Selected');


var bands = ['S2asm','S2con','S2cor','S2var','S2idm','S2savg','S2ent'];

var arrayImage = S2glcm_sel.select(bands).toArray();
print(arrayImage);
var covar = arrayImage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.covariance(),
  maxPixels: 10e9,
  //bestEffort: true
});

var covarArray = ee.Array(covar.get('array'));

var eigens = covarArray.eigen();
var eigenVectors = eigens.slice(1,1);

var principalComponents = ee.Image(eigenVectors)
.matrixMultiply(arrayImage.toArray(1));

var pcImage = principalComponents
//throw out an unneeded diamension, [[]] -> [].
.arrayProject[(0)]
//make one band array image a multi-band image, [] -> image.
.arrayFlatten(['pc1','pc2','pc3','pc4','pc5','pc6','pc7']);

Map.addLayer(pcImage.select('pc1'),{},'pc1');
```

But I am getting error "Cannot read property 'arrayFlatten' of undefined" at line 58.
I have copied pca code given in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304399/principal-component-analysis-pca-issue-on-spectral-indices-and-transformations). It seems to be working fine in the give question. What I am doing wrong? Is it because scale or I am missing something important.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on line 60:

```
.arrayProject[(0)]
```

should be

```
.arrayProject([0])
```